# How can I see what time is closest to one is my list?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm developing an app for my mobile phone where you can see bus times you enter a time with a listbox and then it checks the list and then presents you the time closest to it or an exact match. I Have tried myself and had most luck with some code I found on here yet i'm still unable to get it to work.

Here

```
    public  MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> thedates = new List<string>();



        thedates.Add("0130");
        thedates.Add("0230");
        thedates.Add("0330");
        thedates.Add("0430");
        thedates.Add("0530");


        DateTime fileDate, closestDate;


        int min = int.MaxValue;

        foreach (DateTime date in theDates)
            if (Math.Abs(date.Ticks - fileDate.Ticks) < min)
            {
                min = date.Ticks - fileDate.Ticks;
                closestDate = date;
            }
    }
```

Error:
The name 'theDates' does not exist in the current context.

Sorry if this is something simple or complicated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a very basic error, c# is case sensitive! So change theDates to thedates as you declared it..

Comment: And when you fix that, you'll just get a runtime exception because your actual data is strings, but you're treating them as `DateTime` objects.  You need to parse them, not just cast them, to `DateTime`.  You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` for that, or better yet, just get rid of the strings entirely and start out defining times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change 'theDates' 
in

```
foreach (DateTime date in theDates)
```

to 'thedates'.

As mentioned--you also aren't using the correct objects. You should just create a List of DateTime objects instead of strings.

```
List<DateTime> thedates = new List<DateTime>();

thedates.Add(new DateTime{ // Set up values here });
..
..
```

Comment: theDates.Add(new DateTime{ 1110});
Gives me an error and also an error here Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) On line: min = date.Ticks - fileDate.Ticks;

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

There are many ways to set up the DateTime objects. You just need to decide which way is best for what you want. Since it seems like you're setting hours and minutes (assuming "0430" is 4:30AM), you need either a constructor that takes hours/minutes as a parameter or you need to specify the Hour/Minute properties directly. ------- You can use theDates.Add(new DateTime(0, 0, 0, 3, 29, 0)); which would create a DateTime object that is equal to 4:30AM (indexed from zero).

Comment: States it's ErrorProperty or indexer 'Minute' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Try the constructor version above.

The reason you're getting a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'." is because 'min' is an int, while ticks are of type long. 

Change 'int min = int.MaxValue;' to just 'long min;'

Comment: Heres what I have currently now:http://pastebin.com/zxXjRvbY Presumably if it worked it would see that the "bus time" is at 5:30am and the time inputed would be 4:30am correct? It tells me Cannot use local variable 'fileDate' before it is declared

Comment: http://pastebin.com/K9imb3hL - look at that. It gives you that error because you cannot use something before you create it. You wouldn't be able to use your arm if you didn't have an arm to use, right? I declared the variable before it was used, so the error of trying to use something before you actually have it is gone.

Comment: Okay great. So if I want to get the answer to code it would be textblock1.text = date? or closestdate thank you very much

Comment: I see I will have to convert it to type string to to be able to display it.

Comment: It depends how you want to have your date formatted, but it would be in closestDate. Look at the .ToString for DateTime objects. There are countless ways to format it. Really up to you. http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Also, this pastebin is updated and works (tested it locally) - http://pastebin.com/Zei42iJC . While this uses hard-coded year/month/day.. it doesn't really matter for what you're doing.

Comment: Is  string fixeddate;
                    fixeddate = DateTime.TryParseExact(closestDate);
                    box2.Text = fixeddate; along the right lines? I know it doesn't work but is it wrong completey or?

Comment: If you look at the dotnetperls link above, you'll be able to see a bunch of ways to format the date into a string. You probably just want time, so you would want: closestDate.ToString("HH:mm");

Comment: Thank for all your help! One last question is it possible to add the current time eg DateTime.Now to the FileDate?

Comment: Yeah, you can initialize it to whatever you want. The main thing is just making sure that the DateTimes in theDates (the list) all are on the same day (or different if you choose to pick a time in the future/past, but just be sure they make sense to you).

Comment: I tried using                        fileDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now); and using                         fileDate = new DateTime.Now; but both give errors can you advise? thanks

Comment: The first error is because (I think) you can't instantiate a DateTime with another DateTime (no constructor to handle this). You could have just done: fileDate = DateTime.Now; ... The second is because you don't need the 'new' keyword. Like I said - fileDate = DateTime.Now;

Comment: It doesn't get the correct time when I use datetime.now it doesn't change either. No error just invalid results

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic error and should be found almost everywhere on the internet, the problem is that you are searching with your `foreach` loop in a `list` called `theDates`, that doesn't exists in your application.

You declared the `list`: `thedates` at the top of your application and you want to use `theDates`, you could rename `thedates` to `theDates` or just change `theDates` to `thedates` in your foreach loop.

You should also change your `List<string>` to a `List<DateTime>`.

The `list<DateTime>` will be filled as follow:

```
theDates.Add(today.AddHours(13).AddMinutes(30));
theDates.Add(today.AddHours(14).AddMinutes(30));
theDates.Add(today.AddHours(15).AddMinutes(30));
theDates.Add(today.AddHours(16).AddMinutes(30));
theDates.Add(today.AddHours(17).AddMinutes(30));
```

Remember: c# is a *case sensitive* language.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)                                  On line:   min = date.Ticks - fileDate.Ticks;

Comment: You should insert valid datetimes at thedates.Add(valid datetime here); You are doing strongs now

Comment: What would an example look like? "12:30" "1230" or something else?

Comment: I added 'How to' in the answer

Comment: What would today be? Today = Datetime.now;?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx it gets the current date and time of this computer.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are creating a list "thedates" and in foreach is working on "theDates", Variables are case sensitive
2. after you change anyone of the both, still there will be problems as your thedates container is a list of strings and your foreach loop is expecting a container containing Datetime Objects

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way is to do a simple LINQ query. I just moved your ticks math into the select statement then tack on a call to `Min()` to get the smallest element in the result set.

```
  closetDate = myDates.Select(Math.Abs(x => x.Ticks - fileDate.Ticks)).Min()
```